# Sacar diferencia de la cantidad obtenida del primer y último día del mes

Tags: sql, jquery, sql-server, base-de-datos, datatable

Estoy realizando una query en SQL en la cual pueda obtener el dato del campo dm.Dato del primer día de cada mes y el último día de cada mes y realizar una resta entre estos para saber la diferencia por mes de estos datos.

Este es mi código actual:

```
DECLARE @FechaInicial DATE = '2024-01-01';
DECLARE @FechaFinal DATE = '2024-12-31';
SELECT 
    YEAR(dm.Fecha) AS Año,
    MONTH(dm.Fecha) AS Mes,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_006_Oficinas'
                THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL(dp.Dato, 0)
            ELSE 0
        END) AS ELFO_006_Oficinas_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_007_Rim'
                THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL(dp.Dato, 0)
            ELSE 0
        END) AS ELFO_007_Rim_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_008_ED'
                THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL(dp.Dato, 0)
            ELSE 0
        END) AS ELFO_008_ED_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_009_FBW'
                THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL(dp.Dato, 0)
            ELSE 0
        END) AS ELFO_009_FBW_Diferencia,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dm.Linea = 'ELFO_010_Disco'
                THEN dm.Dato - ISNULL(dp.Dato, 0)
            ELSE 0
        END) AS ELFO_010_Disco_Diferencia
FROM Dato_Medidor dm
LEFT JOIN Dato_Medidor dp ON DATEPART(DAY, dm.Fecha) = 1
    AND YEAR(dp.Fecha) = YEAR(dm.Fecha)
    AND MONTH(dp.Fecha) = MONTH(dm.Fecha)
    AND DATEPART(DAY, dp.Fecha) = DAY(EOMONTH(dp.Fecha))
    AND dm.Linea = dp.Linea
WHERE dm.Fecha BETWEEN @FechaInicial AND @FechaFinal
    AND DATEPART(HOUR, dm.Fecha) = 7
    AND DATEPART(MINUTE, dm.Fecha) = 0
GROUP BY YEAR(dm.Fecha), MONTH(dm.Fecha)
ORDER BY YEAR(dm.Fecha), MONTH(dm.Fecha);
```

actualmente me esta devolviendo esto

| YEAR | MONTH | ELFO_006_Oficinas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024 | 1 | 402099 |

y el resultado esperado es este

| YEAR | MONTH | ELFO_006_Oficinas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024 | 1 | 909 |

que es la resta de la cantidad que se tiene guadada en el campo dm.Dato del primer dia del mes y el dato de ese mismo campo el ultimo dia del mes

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta separar la consulta en dos para poder obtener la consulta en dos partes. Una para el valor del primer mes  y otra para el ultimo día del mes y luego restar los valores.

```
DECLARE @FechaInicial DATE = '2024-01-01';
DECLARE @FechaFinal DATE = '2024-12-31';

WITH PrimerDia AS (
    SELECT 
        YEAR(Fecha) AS Año,
        MONTH(Fecha) AS Mes,
        Linea,
        Dato AS DatoPrimerDia
    FROM Dato_Medidor
    WHERE DATEPART(DAY, Fecha) = 1
        AND Fecha BETWEEN @FechaInicial AND @FechaFinal
        AND DATEPART(HOUR, Fecha) = 7
        AND DATEPART(MINUTE, Fecha) = 0
),
UltimoDia AS (
    SELECT 
        YEAR(Fecha) AS Año,
        MONTH(Fecha) AS Mes,
        Linea,
        Dato AS DatoUltimoDia
    FROM Dato_Medidor
    WHERE DATEPART(DAY, Fecha) = DAY(EOMONTH(Fecha))
        AND Fecha BETWEEN @FechaInicial AND @FechaFinal
        AND DATEPART(HOUR, Fecha) = 7
        AND DATEPART(MINUTE, Fecha) = 0
)
SELECT 
    p.Año,
    p.Mes,
    p.Linea,
    u.DatoUltimoDia - p.DatoPrimerDia AS Diferencia
FROM PrimerDia p
JOIN UltimoDia u ON p.Año = u.Año AND p.Mes = u.Mes AND p.Linea = u.Linea
ORDER BY p.Año, p.Mes;
```

Comment: muchas gracias Stefan es lo que buscaba